# fetch local json data in react js (outside of public folder or src folder)

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch, fetch-api

as the Question title. Is there any way to fetch local json data without putting the json file under **public** or **src** folder in react? so what I need is as below image (**red circle**):

[image]

and my fetch code is like below (**it didn't get anything**):

```
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
     useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`../server/testData.json`)
         .then((res) => res.json())
         .then((data) => setMovies(data))
         .catch((err) => err);
     }, []);
```

the target that I would like to achive is like below:

[image]

If I put the json file under public folder and change fetch code to `fetch("./testData.json")` or put the file under src folder and import the json file normaly without using `fetch` function/api and map ex. `import data from "./testData.json"` then `data.map(value => value)` I achieved as the above image, but the problem is I wanted to fetch the json file from outside of both folder (public & src). Is there any way to do that?

Comment: No. `fetch()` requires something to **serve** the resource (file). When your app is built, only files that are bundled or placed into the `public` folder are _served_ by your web server. You should be able to bundle the file though via `import`, no matter where it is

Comment: use `json-server` library it is  better to use. It allows you to make http requests

Comment: Thanks @Phil, but I'v tried not using `fetch` and use the `import`. If I use import it should be under `src` or else I will get error like this `./src/Home.js
Module not found: You attempted to import ../server/testData.json which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.`

Comment: Ah right, sorry. I wasn't aware of that restriction

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mock fetch for development and testing take a look at [MSW](https://mswjs.io/docs/)
It was built for exactly that use case.

If not just import the json without using fetch.